# INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not work as expected

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time using insert.. on duplicate, I have a issue. My insert on duplicate update does not exactly work as I would have expected, for example every time I try to update a table within my DB, a new row is inserted into the DB rather than the row being updated as expected. Very strange. I was wondering if someone would have a look and pass your take on it. 
I have a primary and unique key by the way.

```
  if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['a']);
        $b = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['b']);
        $c = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['c']);

        $insert = "INSERT INTO details
  ( a
  , b
  , c
  ) 
  VALUES
  ( ?
  , ?
  , ?
  ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE a  = VALUES (a)
  , b  = VALUES(b)
  , c  = VALUES(c)";

        $row = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($row, 'sss',$a $b, $c);

        /* execute query */
        $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($row);

        if ($execute) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "error ";
        }
      }
```

TABLE

```
  CREATE TABLE `Rest_Details` (
  `A` int(34) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `B` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `C` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`A`),
  UNIQUE KEY `B` (`B`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: If you want to update a row, use `UPDATE`.  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does not usually make sense when you have an auto-increment primary key included in the columns and values of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$insert` query is missing a close quote:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO details
  ( a
  , b
  , c
  ) 
  VALUES
  ( ?
  , ?
  , ?
  ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE a  = VALUES (a)
  , b  = VALUES(b)
  , c  = VALUES(c)"
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, unfortunately i am still having the same issues